# Wait until function is completed

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have to function for adding two sprites and moving, called Space1 and Space2. I need to make Space1 move Right to Left, after Space 1 is finished the moving. Then, Space2 will move Left to Right.

I can make them move by 2 functions Move1() and Move2(); but they started the same time.
How can I make the Space2 wait until the function Move1 of Space1 is completed and then Space2 start moving?

This is my code

```
// Create sprite
        let space1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Spaceship")
        space1.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: frame.height/2)
        space1.xScale = 0.3;
        space1.yScale = 0.3;
        space1.name = "space1";
        self.addChild(space1);

        let space2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Spaceship")
        space2.position = CGPoint(x: frame.width, y:0)
        space2.xScale = 0.3;
        space2.yScale = 0.3;
        space2.name = "space2";
        self.addChild(space2);

        let actualDuration = random(min: CGFloat(1), max: CGFloat(3))
        // Create the actions
        let actionMove1 = SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: frame.width, y: frame.height/2), duration: NSTimeInterval(actualDuration))

        let actionMove2 = SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), duration: NSTimeInterval(actualDuration))


        self.runAction(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.runAction(actionMove1, onChildWithName: "space1"),SKAction.runAction(actionMove2, onChildWithName: "space2")]))
```

Answer (score 2):

SpriteKit provides something called [`SKAction.sequence`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/sequence:). You can give it an array of actions which will be started after the one before has finished:

```
func startAction(){
    var space1 = SKSpriteNode()
    var space2 = SKSpriteNode()
    var move1 = SKAction()
    var move2 = SKAction()

    space1.name = "space1"
    space2.name = "space2"

    self.runAction(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.runAction(move1, onChildWithName: "space1"), SKAction.runAction(move2, onChildWithName: "space2")]))
}
```

As you see here, I add names to the SKSpriteNodes. That's important because as you can see in the sequence, you have to specify, on which node the action is getting called.

Also important to say is, that if you use sub-sequences, you need to work with `SKAction.waitForDuration(sec: NSTimeInterval)`. For example:

```
self.runAction(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.runAction(move1, onChildWithName: "space1"), SKAction.waitForDuration(move1.duration), SKAction.runAction(move2, onChildWithName: "space2")]))}
```

Comment: For some reason this doesn't make the actions run in a sequence. They start together.

Comment: Try to add the SkAction.waitForDuration(move1.duration) between your two actions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the completion handler of `runAction` function to get what you need. Start the next `SKAction` inside the `completion handler` of the first `runAction` function.

```
space1.runAction(actionMove1, completion: { () -> Void in
    space2.runAction(actionMove2)
})
```